# Flutter disconnect and dispose bluetooth devices in proper method

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im using flutter reactive plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

For connect and fetching data from multiple devices.

Successfully i have connected to multiple bluetooth devices(4 devices) to receive data

My question is how to disconnect multiple devices at a time.

In the reactive ble document i found that, disconnect only works for last connected device.  Can someone eloborate about how to disconnect multiple devices at a time

Answer (score -1):

As you connect to devices save a list of the DiscoveredDevice.
When you want to disconnect, just loop through the list and disconnect each.

Comment: flutter_reactive_ble doesn't support that. The flutter_reactive_ble can only do cancel the connecting stream, but that is also for the lasted connected device.