# Flutter reactive ble - disconnect any device by deviceId

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

Example:

- I have 3 BLE devices connected in my application; A, B and C
- They connected in that order
- Now I unplug the power from device A, so it should timeout and
  disconnect

But then I read on stack overflow that:
*flutter_reactive_ble doesn't support that. The flutter_reactive_ble can only do cancel the connecting stream, but that is also for the lasted connected device.*

Can anyone already working with this library confirm this statement from:
[Flutter disconnect and dispose bluetooth devices in proper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691707/flutter-disconnect-and-dispose-bluetooth-devices-in-proper-method)

One would expect that `Future<void> disconnect(String deviceId)` from the package would be able to disconnect any connected ble device by it's `deviceId` at any time (not just device C, which was last connected). Could someone elaborate? Official package documentation doesn't offer any info regarding disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

The `flutter_reactive_ble` package does not have a `disconnect` method, so yes, that functionality is not supported.

Here is more information from the developer on why there is no disconnect method:

https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/322#issuecomment-989102539

Comment: But what is then a purpose of disconnect(String deviceId) in their BleDeviceConnector class? https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/blob/master/example/lib/src/ble/ble_device_connector.dart

Comment: That method is defined in the `example` folder, it's not a part of the library.